# Someone placed a command block that resets the world back to a certain date

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend made this realm over 2 months ago and we abandoned it because someone placed a command block that resets it to a certain date. And now since the command block has been placed we can't build or do anything cause when we log out it resets.

What do we do?

Comment: Resetting the entire world is not something a command block can sanely do.

Answer (score 0):

from the server Eula file try disallow the commandblocks so all the commandblocks will jsut be stopped working then try join the server and remove the commandblock then allow commandblocks again and tryr join and hopefully it must work but if your friend was realy tricky he would of placed many commandblocks at many places and also that happened to me once on my skyblock server